# JQuery .attr and .data method gives different value for same attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html code

```
<li class="current" title="some title" data-atype="some type" data-aid="119697371285186601">
  Some text
</li>
```

This is what I get from the firebug / google chrome debugger console,

```
>> $().jquery
"1.7.2"
>> ($('li.current:first')).data('aid')
119697371285186610
>> ($('li.current:first')).attr('data-aid')
"119697371285186601"
```

I searched for the issue and I could not find the exact reason and solution for the issue. If anybody could help me to find out a solution and the cause of the problem, it would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is it transposing the last two digits as in your post?  Or is the only problem the string vs number data types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.fn.data` tries to be smart about numeric types and converts them to integers. Integers however, in JavaScript, are nothing but floats and, thus, get less precise as they approach larger values. I’d stick with `attr()` since that will always return a string. There is also a [ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7579) for this but it’s marked “WONTFIX”. For more information on the limitations of large numbers in JavaScript, see [this article](http://www.2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
   <li class="current" title="some title" data-atype="some type" data-rrr="11969737128518660155555">
  Some text
   </li>
</ul>
<span></span>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span').html('DATA ATTRIBUTE: '+$('li.current:first').data('rrr')+ '   <br />   ATTRIBUTE: '+     $('li.current:first').attr('data-rrr'));
});

Output / result:  

    Some text        
    DATA ATTRIBUTE: 1.1969737128518661e+22
    ATTRIBUTE: 11969737128518660155555
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/usydd/#base

//========================================================//

```
  <ul>
    <li class="current" title="some title" data-atype="some type" data-test1="119697371285186601555" data-test2="11969737128518660155555">Some text
    </li>
</ul>
<span></span>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span').html('DATA ATTRIBUTE: <br />' + $('li.current:first').data('test1')+  ' , <br /> '+$('li.current:first').data('test2') + '<br /><br /> ATTRIBUTE: <br />' + $('li.current:first').attr('data-test1')+' , <br />'+$('li.current:first').attr('data-test2'));
});​


Out Put For jquery version < 1.7.2

Some text
DATA ATTRIBUTE: 
119697371285186610000 , 
1.1969737128518661e+22

ATTRIBUTE: 
119697371285186601555 , 
11969737128518660155555
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ycsje/)

```
Out Put For jquery version 1.8.2

Some text
DATA ATTRIBUTE: 
119697371285186601555 , 
11969737128518660155555

ATTRIBUTE: 
119697371285186601555 , 
11969737128518660155555
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/5JH5N/)

Comment: @nkm: output is coming for jquery 1.8.2